# Input type file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I have a question to ask, I don't know if it's possible.
I should open a server-side excel file inside a php page, I have no problem doing it with
`<input type="file"...>` except that I have to click every time I enter the page and load the file.
Below is the code I use now to load the .xlsx file:

```html
 <div id="mainDiv" class="form">
        <input name="inputVal" id="inputVal" ref="fileInput" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">

        <!--onchange="getFileName()-->
        <div id="divImg" class="imgLoadFile" style="align-content: center;">
            <img src="../images/upload.png"  class="mx-2">
            Carica i tuoi file qui o SFOGLIA
        </div>
        <div id="divBassoTabella" class="w3-row" style="overflow: auto; border-radius: 2px;">
            <table id="myTable" data-table-theme="default zebra"
                   style="/*background: cornsilk;*/ text-align: center!important;">
                <thead></thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <br>

 </div>
```

```js
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('inputVal');
    var arrayDataEXCEL = new Array();
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
            readXlsxFile(fileInput.files[0], {dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'}).then(function (data) {

            $('#divBassoTabella').show();
            $('#divImg').hide();
            $('#mainDiv').removeClass("form");
            $('#inputVal').hide();
          
            $("#myTable tr").remove();
       
            arrayDataEXCEL = data;

            var i = 0;
            data.map((row, index) => {
               if (i == 0) {
                    let myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
                    creaIntestazioneTabella(myTable, row);
                } else {
                    let myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
                    creaRigheTabella(myTable, row);
                }

                i++;
            });
        });
    });
```

I would like to ensure that when entering the page the file is opened directly, therefore the file selection step is skipped, therefore the default file name is given and the file can be read directly.

Comment: If the file is on the server, why not read it with PHP code and produce the output you want on the page there?

Comment: What are you using for `readXlsxFile()` - most libraries allow a string, so you could output that string as part of the HTML / js or get via ajax

Comment: "*open a server-side excel file*" but `<input type='file'>` will open a *client-side* file - unless you have a network share to the "server-side" file and it's accessible to the user

Comment: there's no server side in that code.. what you are trying to accomplish there is just reading a file loaded locally and showing its content on the DOM.  So it's impossible to give any hint on how to trigger the action on page load since probably it's not aiming in the right direction to begin with

Comment: I had focused on javascript for convenience in managing the data since I was running the tests locally but rightly on the server then I won't have the same directories. I will use php, thanks

Comment: so you actually need a php code that will read an Excel file and will return a response with its content encoded in html? that's quite a different question indeed

Comment: if that's what you are looking for, you might be interested in [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/)

Comment: otherwise if you want to stick with the clientside js solution to read the file, you'd need a way to expose the file you talked about stored on the server, so that it will be loaded by your page with an ajax request and processed by your own code